# CONSULTA INNER JOIN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

a la hora del inner join me dice que el valor n_clases no existe... pongo el enunciado y mi código. Un saludo.

**6.- Decrementar un año de experiencia a los profesores de pilates que han impartido menos de 3 clases en el último año. (Debes hacerlo con una única sentencia).**

```
UPDATE PROFESOR_PILATES p
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) n_clases, numero_trabajador_pilates
    FROM imparte pp
    WHERE n_clases < 3 and YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
    GROUP BY numero_trabajador_pilates
    ) clases ON clases.Numero_trabajador_pilates = p.Numero_trabajador_pilates
    SET anos_experiencia = anos_experiencia - 1;
```

Y las tablas profesor de pilates e imparte.

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS PROFESOR_PILATES (
    numero_trabajador_pilates char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    anos_experiencia smallint,
    CONSTRAINT PROF_PIL_FK FOREIGN KEY (numero_trabajador_pilates) REFERENCES PROFESIONALES(numero_trabajador) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

create table IF NOT EXISTS imparte (
    numero_trabajador_pilates char(5),
    codigo_sala char(3),
    fecha date,
    hora time,
    PRIMARY KEY(numero_trabajador_pilates,codigo_sala, fecha, hora),
    CONSTRAINT IMP_PIL_FK FOREIGN KEY (numero_trabajador_pilates) REFERENCES PROFESOR_PILATES(numero_trabajador_pilates) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT COD_IMP_FK FOREIGN KEY (codigo_sala) REFERENCES SALAS(codigo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Es `COUNT(*) AS n_clases`, si no le dices `AS`, intenta buscar la columna llamada `n_clases`

Comment: @javdromero me pone error unknown column 'n_clases' in 'where clause'

Comment: @javdromero ahora error code 1111. invalid use of group function

Comment: Puedes postear data (inserts) de prueba de lo que tienes y la data esperada?

Comment: @javdromero es lo unico que nos dan Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `HAVING` para allí tomar los menores a 3, no es necesario el `COUNT(*)`, más bien el `GROUP BY` y `HAVING` hacen la lógica acá.

```
UPDATE profesor_pilates p
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numero_trabajador_pilates
                   FROM   imparte pp
                   WHERE  Year(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 month)
                   GROUP  BY numero_trabajador_pilates
                   HAVING Count(*) < 3) clases
               ON clases.numero_trabajador_pilates = p.numero_trabajador_pilates
SET    anos_experiencia = anos_experiencia - 1;
```